# Using non-minified CSS during development vs production Maven build

Tags: css, stylesheet, minify

I have no problem implementing a solution in my pom.xml using the samaxes plugin to minify and generate my required example.min.css file, is there script, how can I keep the development environment utilizing the CSS files on the fly without greatly changing the CSS source files?

I have the following code in my xhtml doc:

```
    .
    .
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
          href="/assets/css/forms.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
      href="/assets/css/content.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
          href="/assets/css/images.css"/>
    .
    .
```

My pom creates an example.min.css and saves it in the same location using samaxes beautifully. I want to use this in my page but only in production...I want to be able to keep up with development on the fly on these various files but when I do the maven compile, it generates the example.min.css file from this and I intend on using this instead in production. There's tons of great answers saying which plugins to use to optimize and minify my css and js, I just need to know if there's a best-practice out there to point to them without bringing in another plugin like wr04J or is there some js I can implement that can build a conditional stylesheet statement on the fly if I use a param or something?

Originally I was using the concept of applying a rendered attribute to a ui:fragment tag that would render one way or another depending on a bean property that checked for the existence of the Maven debug property but this generated way too much overhead and just seemed like a bad hack just to get it to work. I need a better, simpler idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of [Minify Maven Plugin](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin) you have to do something like this:

```
if productionEnvironment
  <script src="js/bundle.min.js"/>
else
  <script src="js/bundle.js"/>
end
```

It remains easy enough to debug and you only have to define your source files once (in the pom).
This will, however, be fixed in a future version of the plugin. [Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) might soon become a reality and I'm planning to add support for it very soon.

Comment: Thanks. It pretty much makes sense at the simplest level. Duh.